# Get length of irregular object in a BW or RGB picture and draw it into picture for control

Tags: matlab, object, image-processing, properties, analytics

I face a well known problem which I am not able to solve.
I have the picture of a root (http://cl.ly/image/2W3C0a3X0a3Y). From this picture, I would like to know the length of the longest root (1st problem), the portion of the big roots and the small roots in % (say the diameter as an orientation which is the second problem). It is important that I can distinguish between fine and big roots since this is more or less the aim of the study (portion of them compared between different species). The last thing, I would like to draw a line along the measured longest root to check if everything was measured right.

For the length of the longest root, I tried to use regionprops(), which is not optimal since this assumes an oval as basic shape if I got this right. 
However, the things I could really need support with are in fact:

How can I get the length of the longest root (start point should be the place where the longest root leaves the main root with the biggest diameter)?
Is it possible to distinguish between fine and big roots and can I get the portion of them? (the coin, the round object in the image is the reference)
Can I draw properties like length and diameter into the picture?

I found out how to draw the centriods of ovals and stuff, but I just dont understand how to do it with the proposed values.

I hope this is no double post and this question does not  exists like this somewhere else, if yes, I am sorry for that.

I would like to thank the people on this forum, you do a great job and everybody with a question can be lucky to have you here.

Thank you for the help, 
Phillip

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
EDIT

I followed the proposed solution, the code until now is as followed:

```
clc
clear all
close all

img=imread('root_test.jpg');

labTransformation = makecform('srgb2lab');
labI = applycform(img,labTransformation);

%seperate l,a,b
l = labI(:,:,1);
a = labI(:,:,2);
b = labI(:,:,3);

level = graythresh(l);
bw = im2bw(l);
bw = ~bw;
bw = bwareaopen(bw, 200);
se = strel('disk', 5);
bw2=imdilate(bw, se);
bw2 = imfill(bw2, 'holes');
bw3 =bwmorph(bw2, 'thin', 5);
bw3=double(bw3);
I4 = bwmorph(bw3, 'skel', 200);
%se = strel('disk', 10);%this step is for better visibility of the line
%bw4=imdilate(I4, se);
D = bwdist(I4);
```

This leads my in the skeleton picture - which is a great progress, thank you for that!!!
I am a little bit out at the point where I have to calculate the distances. How can I explain MatLab that it has to calculate the distance from all the small roots to the main root (how to define this?)? For this I have to work with the diameters first, right?

Could you maybe give the one or the other hint more how to accomplish the distance/length problem?

Thank you for the great help till here!

Phillip

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
EDIT2

Ok, I managed to separate the single root parts. This is not what your edit proposed, but at least something. I have the summed length of all roots as well - not too bad. But even with the (I assume) super easy step by step explanation I have never seen such a tree. I stopped at the point at which I have to select an invisible point - the rest is too advanced for me. 
I dont want to waste more of the time and I am very thankful for the help you gave me already.  But I suppose I am too MatLab-stupid to accomplish this :) 
Thanks! Keep going like this, it is really helpful.

Phillip

Answer (score 7):

For a pre-starting point, I don't see the need for a resolution of 3439x2439 for that image, it doesn't seem to add anything important to the problem, so I simply worked with a resized version of 800x567 (although there should be (nearly) no problem to apply this answer to the larger version). Also, you mention `regionprops` but I didn't see any description of how you got your binary image, so let us start from the beginning.

I considered your image in the LAB colorspace, then binarized the L channel by Otsu, applied a dilation on this result considering the foreground as black (the same could be done by applying an erosion instead), and finally removed small components. The L channel gives a better representation of your image than the more direct luma formula, leading to an easier segmentation. The dilation (or erosion) is done to join minor features, since there are quite a bit of ramifications that appear to be irrelevant. This produced the following image:

[image]

At this point we could attempt using the distance transform combined with grey tone anchored skeleton (see Soille's book on morphology, and/or "Order Independent Homotopic Thinning for Binary and Grey Tone Anchored Skeletons" by Ranwez and Soille). But, since the later is not easily available I will consider something simpler here. If we perform hole filling in the image above followed by thinning and pruning, we get a rough sketch of the connections between the many roots. The following image shows the result of this step composed with the original image (and dilated for better visualization):

[image]

As expected, the thinned image takes "shortcuts" due to the hole filling. But, if such step wasn't performed, then we would end up with cycles in this image -- something I want to avoid here. Nevertheless, it seems to provide a decent approximation to the size of the actual roots.

Now we need to calculate the sizes of the branches (or roots). The first thing is deciding where the main root is. This can be done by using the above binary image before the dilation and considering the distance transform, but this will not be done here -- my interest is only showing the feasibility of calculating those lengths. Supposing you know where your main root is, we need to find a path from a given root to it, and then the size of this path is the size of this root. Observe that if we eliminate the branch points from the thinned image, we get a nice set of connected components:

[image]

Assuming each end point is the end of a root, then the size of a root is the shortest path to the main root, and the path is composed by a set of connected components in the just shown image. Now you can find the largest one, the second largest, and all the others that can be calculated by this process.

EDIT:

In order to make the last step clear, first let us label all the branches found (open the image in a new tab for better visualization):

[image]

Now, the "digital" length of each branch is simply the amount of pixels in the component. You can later translate this value to a "real-world" length by considering the object added to the image. Note that at this point there is no need to depend on Image Processing algorithms at all, we can construct a tree from this representation and work there. The tree is built in the following manner: 1) find the branching point in the skeleton that belongs to the main root (this is the "invisible point" between the labels 15, 16, and 17 in the above image); 2) create an edge from that point to each branch connected to it; 3) assign a weight to the edge according to the amount of pixels needed to travel till the start of the other branch; 4) repeat with the new starting branches. For instance, at the initial point, it takes 0 pixels to reach the beginning of the branches 15, 16, and 17. Then, to reach from the beginning of the branch 15 till its end, it takes the size (number of pixels) of the branch 15. At this point we have nothing else to visit in this path, so we create a leaf node. The same process is repeated for all the other branches. For instance, here is the complete tree for this labeling (the dual representation of the following tree is much more space-efficient):

[image]

Now you find the largest weighted path -- which corresponds to the size of the largest root -- and so on.

Comment: What function breaks the segments?  Like the invisible point at 15, 16, and 17